# Obj-c codesigning without entering admin password?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask, codesign

Is it possible to 'automatically' codesign bundles via cocoa without the user having to enter their admin username and password each time?
 If there is some way to implement this, some type of working example would be appreciated. Here is the code I'm currently using, which asks for admin credits when executed:

```
- (void)codeSignature:(NSData *)privateKey {

    NSString* signSomething    = @"file";
    NSString* homeDir     = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Users/Rufote"];

    NSString* homePath = [homeDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:signSomething];

    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/usr/bin/codesign"];

    NSArray *args;
    args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-s", @"certificate", @"-vvvv", @"-f", homePath, nil];
    [task setArguments: args];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [string release];
    [task release];

    return;

}

@end
```

Comment: This question is really about ways of accessing the MacOS X Keychain - which stores your certificates and private keys - so its documentation would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Marko - I just finished reading the keychain documentation as you mentioned and it tells me nothing about how to accomplish what I wanting to do. [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1]

Answer (score 1):

On your System keychain, you will find 3 things related to your code signing :
- your certificate
- your private key (same name as your certificate)
- your public key (same name as your certificate)

If you double click on your keys, on Access Control, you *could* chose "allow all applications to access this item". Then you won't have to enter admin password anymore to do code signing, **but beware the security risks** !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to access Keychain's data.

But since you want to codesign your Bundle then you can write Apple/Shell script using [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) and [xcrun](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html) command which will be helpful to automate your codesign process.

Comment: @LukeMcneice:  Can you please elaborate yourself?? How will you do that?? Will it not be unauthorized?? and terminal will ask you for password also....

Comment: Move the certificates to another keychain. Create a password for it. Create a script that unlocks that keychain (using the password) prior to running code sign. It's of corse possible to just unlock it with admin credentials but putting admin credentials as plain text in a script is bad craic.